# Azure LogicApp calculating price

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have these two LogicApps

LogicApp 1

1. Actions: 6
2. Standard Connections: 2
3. Runs: every 5. minute or 8640 exections pr. month (12 * 24 * 30)

LogicApp 2

1. Actions: 3
2. Standard Connections: 2
3. Runs: every 2. minute or 21600 exections pr. month (30 * 24 * 30)

The pricing, according to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/logic-apps/ is:

1. Actions: 0.000025 $
2. Standard connections: 0.000125 $

As i understand it, the pricing is pr. execution.

is it correct to say that the monthly cost of the two functions is:

1. LogicApp 1: (8640 * 6 * 0.000025) + (8640 * 2 * 0.000125) = 3.46 $
2. LogicApp 2: (21600 * 3 * 0.000025) + (21600 * 2 * 0.000125) = 7.02 $

All actions and connections is executed every time.

Comment: Sounds correct for me. check your billing from portal on a daily basis and see if it matches ?

Comment: @Thomas I can't. I run through a reseller. But I just wanted to learn how it is done by hand :) so I can do it for other.

Comment: Oh ok I understand but stackoverflow is for coding question, no really the good place to ask

Comment: Just to add a point If there is any data retention happening in the logic app, its cost is included as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculations seem okay, don't forget that it is only successful and failed actions that are billable.

You can set up an Azure Function to do the actual pulling against any data source and then have the Function do an HTTP call to a `when an http request is received` in logic apps to reduce the times that the trigger will fire, this should be cheaper all the building the azure function costs as well.

If this is a recurring job that is only running on business hours you can set up a job like this with the recurrence trigger and with an interval and frequency like this.

​​​[image: Recurrence business hours]