# How are standard connector charged in consumption plan Azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

If I have a logic app and I am using a standard connector like O365 in a loop, and using it's one action to send email how would that be charged?

E.g. If I call action of standard connector 10 times while in a logic app loop, do I have to pay for connector reference 10 time plus connector action 10 time?

Comment: It appears that this is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974609/azure-logicapp-calculating-price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some test, the result is similar with the post you provided in comments. But I still want to summarize it for your reference:

**1.** If we set the logic app with a "Recurrence" (for example 1 time every day), and there is a standard connector in it. We need to pay for 30 times of standard connector cost every month.

**2.** If we use a "For each" loop(loop 10 times), and there is a standard connector in the "For each" loop. We will also need to pay for 10 times of standard connector cost.

**3.** I confirmed with azure support team. When we use standard connector action, we just need to pay for $0.000125 every execution. Do not need to pay for one normal action plus one standard connector($0.000025 + $0.000125). But here is a [blog](https://peter.intheazuresky.com/2018/03/21/azure-logic-apps-pricing-2018-do-you-still-need-to-be-careful-about-costs/) which mentioned that maybe we need to pay for one normal action plus one standard connector.

screenshot1

[image]

screenshot2:
[image]

So you can also raise a support ticket by yourself on azure portal by following the steps on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to ask azure support team about this question. The support ticket about billing is free.